# Bash: Find any subdirectories without a given file present

Tags: bash, shell, subdirectory

I want to know if my file exists in any of the sub directories below. The sub directories are created in the steps above in my shell script, the below code always tells me the file do not exist (even if it does) and I want the path to be printed as well.

```
#!/bin/bash
....

if ! [[ -e [ **/**/somefile.txt && -s **/**/somefile.txt ]]; then
    echo "===> Warn: somefile.txt was not created in the following path: " 
    # I want to be able to print the path in which file is not generated
    exit 1
fi
```

I know the file name is somefile.txt which is to be created in all sub-directories, but the subdirectory names change a lot.. Hence globbing.

Comment: First -- `**/somefile.txt` only expands to copies of `somefile.txt` that actually exist. If you want to find ones that *don't* exist, that means you need to iterate over directories, and can't include `somefile.txt` in the glob expression.

Comment: Second -- you can't pass a glob expression as an argument to `-e` or `-s`; these test expressions take an exact pathname as an argument, or a *single* filename. They don't take a glob, or a list of multiple files (which a glob can, in some contexts, expand to).

Comment: Third, you need to run `shopt -s extglob` to make `**` have any special meaning. (If you're used to it working out-of-the-box in an interactive shell, one of your dotfiles probably is running this for you).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
#!/bin/bash

shopt -s extglob   ## enable **, which by default has no special behavior

for d in **/; do
  if ! [[ -s "$d/somefile.txt" ]]; then
    echo "===> WARN: somefile.txt was not created (or is empty) in $d" >&2
    exit 1
  fi
done
```

Comment: This is perfect! Thanks a lot Charles. I really wish there was some documentation around this, but this is exactly what I wanted.

Comment: http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/pattern is probably a good place to start for docs on pattern matching (globbing). [BashFAQ #31](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/031) discusses `test`, `[` and `[[` in some depth, and http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/ccmd/conditional_expression is a good reference as well. Is there other content I can help to find docs for?

Comment: The FAQ path (already in bookmarks) and the syntax pattern link helps me a lot. I'd not want more for what I am doing I guess. Thanks again!